# Set grub2 as main bootloader

Tags: linux, grub, grub2, backtrack

I have installed two linux distributions which are kali linux and backtrack 5 and before install backtrack 5 grub2 was the main bootloader but now the main grub is the legacy of backtrack. How can I set grub2 as the main bootloader again?

EDIT:the grub2 is not overwritten but only is not the main bootloader. I tried boot-repair disk but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use @Rio6 answer to make it default and reinstall grub, but if you're on a EFI system, you can use

```
# efibootmgr
```

to list all of the bootloaders installed to the efi boot partition with numbers identifing them, then

```
# efibootmgr -o <insert-number-of-grub2-here>
```

to modify your efi boot order, setting grub2 first.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reinstall grub2

Execute:

```
# grub-install /dev/sda
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

change /dev/sda to the disk you want to install grub on

Comment: It's not replaced it still exist I don't need to reinstall but I need to make it the main bootloader